# undefined local variable or method `blog'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a rails application and I have a Dashboard::user(dashboard/user) controller and I would like for users to update their blog post through the backend of the site. That works fine but when I am trying to get a list of the latest blog post a user has created I get an error.

dashboard/users_controller

```
def content
  @blog = Blog.new
  render ('content')
end
```

dashboard/blogs/_blog_list.html.erb

```
<%= div_for(:dashboard ,blog) do %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(blog.preview.url(:thumb)), dashboard_blog_path(blog) %>
  <h1><%= link_to (blog.title),dashboard_blog_path(blog) %></h1>
   <p><%= truncate blog.excerpt, length: 160 %></p>
  <%= blog.published_at %>
  <%= blog.site_id %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def content
  @site = Site.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
  @blogs = @site.blogs.all
  @blog = Blog.new

  render ('content')
end
```

content.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'dashboard/blogs/blog_list', :locals => {:blogs => @blog} %>
```

Any reason why this is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that the local variable `blog` was never set. `@blog` will be available in the partial, but `blog` will only be available if it is explicitly set, for example if the partial is rendered via

```
render :partial => "blogs/blog_list", :locals => {:blog => @blog}
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Partials for more details about partials.

Comment: Does this also worked if blog is inside of dashboard folder? Rails is throwing the same error at me.

Comment: Can you paste the line that's rendering this partial? Also, have you replaced all occurrences of `blog` with `@blog`?

Comment: now you've defined a local variable `blogs`, but are still referencing `blog`

Comment: the blogs is the name of the controller but I am not able to figure out how to access the variable. I will keep trying by messing with the code. Your answer above is probably correct

Comment: When you use `render :partial => 'dashboard/blogs/blog_list', :locals => {:blogs => @blog}`, you're saying "render the _blog_list partial, and inside it bind the local variable `blogs` to `@blog`". If you change `:blogs` there to just `blog` then it should work as you desire.

Comment: The above worked and I think the problem lies within my controller. Can you take a look at the above and see if there is something wrong with my controller code? I do appreciate the help you are providing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10252/discussion-between-ben-taitelbaum-and-coletrain)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
div_for(:dashboard ,blog)
```

Is ':dashboard' supposed to be the prefix for the value of the id attribute of your div tag? That is, you want to get something like this?

```
<div id='dashboard_blog_123'>...</div>
```

You have this the wrong way around. Try

```
div_for(blog, :dashboard)
```

If that doesn't fix it, look at how your partial is being rendered and whether it is supplying a local variable called 'blog'.